# Excluding files from assets:precompile in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, less, asset-pipeline, precompile

I use codekit for writing less which it then converts to css automatically.

I don't want rails to convert my less files to css, I rather codekit do it.

if I precompile the assets via

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I get

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- less
```

How do I **exclude** a specific folder/file types from precompiling? (all my less files are in app/assets/stylesheets/less and the css (which I do want to be precompiled) are in app/assets/stylesheets/css

**update**

deleting `application.less` solves this but how do I excluding it from processing in the first place?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) guide:

> The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js,
>   application.css and all non-JS/CSS files (i.e., .coffee and .scss
>   files are not automatically included as they compile to JS/CSS):

```
[ Proc.new{ |path| !File.extname(path).in?(['.js', '.css']) }, /application.(css|js)$/ ]
```

> If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript
>   files to include, you can add them to the precompile array:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
```

So, I would say that your solution is to modify `config.assets.precompile` to exclude `.less` files. Maybe something like this (in a suitable environment file, like `config/environments/production.rb`):

```
config.assets.precompile = [ Proc.new{ |path| !File.extname(path).in?(['.js', '.css', '.less']) }, /application.(css|js)$/ ]
```

Comment: This fails because Rails doesn't know what to do with the `less` files. Adding the `less-rails` gem to your app might remove the error but is not the solution you've asked in the question.

Comment: ok correction - this works when I put it in production.rb.. not it application.rb.. any only with bundle exec

Answer (score 1):

If your directory structure under the app/assets folder is so:

```
application.css
/css
 (generated by code kit)
 |...home.css
 |...index.css
/less
 |...home.less (assuming this is the extension)
 |...index.less
```

Then, in your application.css file, there must be a directive that says `*= require_tree .` This tells rails to scan all the files/directories and try to compile all the files into one css file.

Change this to `*= require_directory ./css` and it will load the files under the `css` directory for compilation.

Comment: still same :( its worth noting that my tree is /css/application.css and /less/application.less

Comment: Ah! That would fail since application.css is the main file into which the sub-assets would be compiled to.